# Big O notation and Proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f \in O(h) $, does that mean there will always be some $c$, such that $f(n) \leq ch(n) $ is always true for all $n \geq 1$? That is, assuming $f$ and $h$ are always $>0$.

Comment: Not necessary; for example, consider when $h$ is zero over some bounded interval.

Comment: When we use the big or small o notation. We have to define the neighborhood in which the notation makes sense. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

$f=O(h)$ means that there exists a constant $c$ such that $|f(n)|\leq c|h(n)|$ holds for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Ok. So is the statement false? If so, do you have a counter-example?

Comment: @u7283 If $n$ is meant to be only going through natural numbers, i.e. you are looking at sequences, and if $h$ is strictly positive, then your statement is also true. You can always increase $c$ to account for whatever happens at the initial part before $n$ gets sufficiently large.

Comment: That's what I thought, but how do I go about formalizing a proof for that?

Answer (score -1):

No. The big O notation means that, for sufficiently large values of $x$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ behaves similar up to a constant, that is:

$$ f=O(h) \Longleftrightarrow \exists M\in\mathbb R^* : \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = M \lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) \Longleftrightarrow\\ \Longleftrightarrow M\in\mathbb R^* \mbox{ and } x_0\in R^+: f(x) \leq Mg(x) \; \forall x\geq x_0 . $$

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean  "for large value of x", for example we can use the big  O notation to write the remainder term of the Taylor expansion which can be defined in any neighborhood we choose.

Comment: The big O notation does not imply anything about the existence of a limit. And it doesn't mean "similar", that would be $\Theta$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I based my answer on this notes: http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf